# How to scale a line with sub-pixel width in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I want to display zoomed images with lines and polygons in original image coordinate system, where pixel is always 1x1 square regardless of display zoom. For example, I would like to display a thin line segment from the center of pixel (0, 0) to the center of pixel (9, 9), but the code snippet below produces a thick line because the scale is so high:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int scale = 44;

  QApplication   a(argc, argv);
  QGraphicsScene scene;
  QGraphicsView  view(&scene);
  QImage         image("test.bmp");
  auto           line = new QGraphicsLineItem (0.5, 0.5, 9.5, 9.5);

  line->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
  scene.addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
  scene.addItem(line);
  view.scale(scale, scale);
  view.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

How can I make this line thin, such that it has sub-pixel thickness *before* applying the scale to the width, such that the final thickness is smaller than the value of `scale`?

This could be achieved by using rescaled coordinates (scale*0.5, scale*0.5, scale*9.5, scale*9.5) for line position, but I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [void QPen::setWidth(int width)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpen.html#setWidth) and  [void QPen::setWidthF(qreal width)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpen.html#setWidthF).

```
QPen pen(Qt::blue);
pen.setWidth(0);

line->setPen(pen);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there a way to set fractional pen widths? I noticed that `0` sets pen width to one display pixel and `1` sets it to `scale` pixels, but there are no widths in between.

Comment: While this is possible, you need to set the width dependent of the scale. There is a much easier solution - see my answer.

Comment: Not "regardless of display zoom", as you requested. You need to `setWidthF(theWidthYouWant / scale)` to achieve what you want, unless you have a look at my answer ;)

Comment: @leemes _regardless of display zoom_ means `pen.setWidthF(0.5)` produces 0.5 pixel wide line regardless of `scale` value, which it does.

Comment: If your scale is for example 10, and you `setWidthF(0.5)`, then it is rendered as 5 pixels on screen. If you also `setCosmetic(true)`, then it is a 0.5 pixels thick line. Maybe your scale was just small enough you didn't notice that thickness still scales unless you set it to cosmetic.

Comment: See this illustration of a simplified program: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oBdDs.png (I hope graphics scene behaves the same than directly painting to a widget)

Comment: @leemes _ it is rendered as 5 pixels on screen_ that's correct, but I don't care about display pixels, I care only about _original image coordinate system_, so I want it to be 0.5 original image pixel size, regardless how large it is on the display.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I thought you want the opposite, that the line width should measured in screen pixels regardless of the scale. Sorry then. ;) I delete my answer. Also clarified your question in an edit. You can revert it if you dislike the edit.